# How to determine elevation of points in shapefile from second shapefile using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, data, elevation

I am a bit new to ArcGIS and have run into a snag.

I have a series of points in a shapefile that only have x and y coordinates. Additionally I have a series of other points in a separate shapefile that have x, y, and z coordinates. I have added both to a map and have generated contours from the latter of the two files.

My question is: Is it possible to determine the elevations of the points in the first shapefile based on the second shapefile and contours and if so how?

Comment: Do you have the 3D Analyst Extension?

Comment: Yes along with ArcScan, Geostatistical Analyst, Maplex, Network Analyst, Publisher, Schematics, Spatial Analyst, and Tracking Analyst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the 3D analyst Extension is available, here is how I would solve the problem:

1. Using the shapefile containing the heights, I would interpolate and create a DEM. There are many tools for this, such as [IDW](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/IDW/00q90000001s000000/), [Spline](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Spline/00q900000024000000/) and [Trend](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Trend/00q90000006s000000/), but I would suggest that you use [Topo to Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Topo_to_Raster/00q90000000s000000/) tool. In My experience, this produces the most realistic output amongst all the tools.
2. Once you have the DEM raster, use the [Extract Values to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Extract_Values_to_Points/009z0000002t000000/) tool, to get the Z values for the input points(the shapefile having only x & y)

Comment: @user23272: Glad to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the 3D Analyst extension, you could convert your contour shapefile to a TIN and then drape the 2D shapefile over it.  You can then interpolate the z coordinates using the Interpolate Shape tool (also in 3D Analyst).

[This PDF](http://downloads2.esri.com/ESRIpress/images/144/GISTutorial_samplechapter.pdf/) will walk you through creating the TIN from the contours and also the draping part.  The part you want begins on pg. 6 of the PDF file.

In addition, [this link](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Interpolate_Shape_%283D_Analyst%29/) provides background on the Interpolate Shape tool.

Hope this helps!!